# displaying divs in different layers?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, hide

I created a navigation menu for my website in javascript.
When i click on a div like 'About', it will show other divs below like 'About this website', 'Contact me'.

The problem is, that every text below the expanded Menu is also going below to make room for the menu. when i close the menu again, the texts below come back up.

I want to put the expanded menu into a second layer and make it transparent.
So the texts below wont change their position and the expanded menu goes over the content below.
[image]
after alot of tries to get this menu even running, I ended up using a simple 
structure containing divs & grids.

```
<main>
  <div class=navGrid>
    //Example of one Menu containing links
    <div class=navMenuX onclick="clickNavMenu(1)">
      <div>Example Title</div>
      <div id=1>
        <div class=navLink>Link 0</div>
        <div class=navLink>Link 1</div>
        <div class=navLink>Link 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </main>




 <style>
  //horizontalMenu (columns)
  .navMenuGrid{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    display: grid;
  }
  .navMenuX{  
    //verticalMenu (rows)
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.1fr;
    display: grid;
  }
<style>



<script>
    function loadNav(){
      console.log("loaded navigation menu.");
      for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    clicks=0;
    lastparam = "none";
    function clickNavMenu(param){
      if(lastparam != param) clicks=0;
      if(clicks==2) clicks=0;
      console.log("clicked item"+param+" in navMenu.");
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
      if(clicks == 0)
        document.getElementById(param).style.display = "inline-block";
      clicks++;
      lastparam = param;
    }
  </script>
```

Is it possible to add layers to divs across the document?

I want the div:

```
  <div id=i>
    <div class=navLink>Link 0</div>
    <div class=navLink>Link 1</div>
    <div class=navLink>Link 2</div>
  </div>
```

to be in the second layer of the document,
So everything except those divs are in the first layer.

Then finally i want to have all items of the second layer above all items on the first layer.

Has anyone made similiar attempts and knows where to look?

Comment: Simply style the div that should be above the others with: `position:relative; background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);` -- that's all you need.

Comment: thank you..  lol sometimes its the easy things..

Answer (score 0):

I added a class for this div.

```
  <div class=navGroup id=i> // < < < < < fix
    <div class=navLink>Link 0</div>
    <div class=navLink>Link 1</div>
    <div class=navLink>Link 2</div>
  </div>
```

This class has an absolute position

```
  .navGroup {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(245,245,245, 0.6);
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(130,180,220, 0.5);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(130,180,220, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(130,180,220, 0.5);
    position: absolute; // < < < < < fix
    width: 20%;
  }
```

The text below (main) has a relative position now

```
main {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative; // < < < < < fix
}
```

this fixed the problem entirely.

Comment: We don't close the "thread". You can simply mark your answer as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.